# Query regarding Injectivity proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Given the mapping $f: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and another mapping exists such that $g: \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ where $g(x)=5f(x)$, could a simple proof that:

$\frac{1}{5} g(x) \rightarrow \Bbb R \Rightarrow g(x)=5\Bbb R$, hence multiplying the set $\Bbb R$ by come constant $n$ has no effect on the entirety of the set and thus $g(x)$ is injective also.

I am not the best at proofs, any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Is $f$ injective here, and are you searching for a proof that also $g$ is injective?

Comment: Yes, sorry for any confusion.

Comment: The notation starting with 1/5*g is gibberish.  Would you edit it to make sense?

Comment: @William My question in the first place was this correct or not...

Comment: @JayVB Your question is not correct.  g(x) = 5R  is meaningless as is 1/5 * g(x) -> R.  Make the necassary edits so that your problem is not nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R$ with $g(x)=g(y)$.

Then $5f(x)=5f(y)$.

Dividing both sides by $5$ we find $f(x)=f(y)$ and conclude that $x=y$.

This on base of the fact that $f$ is injective.

Proved is now that $g$ is injective.

Comment: Isn't this showing $f(x)$ is injective rather than $g(x)$, just replace $5f(x)$ with $0.2g(x)$

Comment: No it is not. It **uses** the injectivity of $f$ to come to that $x=y$. This when we start off with $g(x)=g(y)$. Also the other route can be done: proving injectivity of $f$ on base of injectivity of $g$.